# Is all Ethiopian coffee considered Specialty Grade 1? If so, where can I buy some in Canada?

Tags: specialty-coffee

I was recently introduced to Ethiopian coffee, specifically, a flavour called Honey washed Dawi and Sidamo. They had wonderful aromas and tasted a little bit fruity as well. I did some research and learned that Ethiopian coffee grows at a higher elevation than other coffees, which is why it tastes the way it does. Then, I learned about Specialty Grade 1 coffee that is usually from Ethiopia. Where can I get Grade 1 coffee in Canada?

I found https://www.kickinghorsecoffee.com/en, https://buycoffeecanada and https://etcoffee.com/ Has anyone purchased from these vendors before? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ethiopian coffee is all over the place. [“Specialty”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialty_coffee#Definition) is a coffee that scores over 80 in the SCA scoring system. As such, it is not referred to as a “Grade”.